# Authenticating with facebook on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

I want to authenticate within my app to facebook and after that post programatically on someone elses wall that I have started using my app. Is that possible to do on iPhone? Is there any central authentication module for iphone from which I can use a token to access facebook? I don't want new users to need to type in credentials into my app and after that again have to type in credentials to facebook.

Thanks, Maciej

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

The method you'll call is in `Facebook.m`. Here's an example:

```
[self.facebook authorizeWithPermissions:somePermissions delegate:self];
```

Once you've called the `authorizeWithPermissions`, you will receive some delegate call backs:

```
/**
 * Called when the user has logged in successfully.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
   // Do something with self.facebook.expirationDate and self.facebook.accessToken 
}
```

With `self.facebook.expirationDate` and `self.facebook.accessToken`, you might wish to save them in the `NSUserDefaults` so the user doesn't have to reauthorise every time.

Answer (score 0):

use OAuth for authentication and graph api of facebook..

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook Graph API.. read [developers documentation](http://developer.facebook.com)